Deriving the density of a truncated random variable.
$T$ and $R$ are two independent continuous random variables. Let $(R^*, T^*)$ denote truncated random variables such that $(R, T)|T < R$,
Show that the density of $T^*$ is
\begin{align*}
 f_{T^*}(t)=\frac{P(R>t)f_T(t)}{\int^{\infty}_0{P(R>s)f_T(s)ds}}
\end{align*}
Below is my proof. However, I am not sure whether it is meaningful to specify $T=t$ in the probability function here since $T$ is continuous
\begin{align*}
 f_{T^*}(t)&=f_{T|T<R}(t) \\
           &=P(T=t|T<R)  \\
           &=\frac{P(T=t,T<R)}{P(T<R)} \\
        &=\frac{P(T=t,T<R)}{\int^{\infty}_{s=0}P(T=s, T<R)ds} \\        
        &=\frac{P(T=t,t<R)}{P(T<R)} \\
        &=\frac{P(T=t,t<R)}{\int^{\infty}_{0}P(T=s, s<R)ds} \\        
        &=\frac{P(T=t)P(R>t)}{\int^{\infty}_{0}P(T=s)P(R>s)ds} \because T \perp R \\    
        &=\frac{f_{T}(t)P(R>t)}{\int^{\infty}_{0}f_{T}(s)P(R>s)ds} \because T \perp R \\    
\end{align*}
